# Send more than 50 App Requests

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I want to send an app request to all friends, even if they have more than 50. Right now I have it grab all friends, and have it prompt them more than once in batches of 50, but this can be pretty redundant and tiring for the user. I was just wondering if there is a way to do more than 50 by somehow having the app do the request on the backend, or send a request without prompting.

I've heard of "Friction-less Requests", but that only works if the user has sent requests to the user before.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't bulk-send requests like this without user interaction, even frictionless requests where the user doesn't need to confirm each individual request will only work if the user has already confirmed at least one request and enabled the option to not be prompted next time.

I struggle to think of a scenario in which this would be anything other than spam, and i imagine if you have a system which forces >50 requests to be sent, that you'll trigger spam filters pretty quickly